# How to solve IllegalArgumentException WindowManagerGlobal:findViewLocked

Tags: android, crash

My application is getting crashed due to the following error:

> **Illegal Argument Exception (@Window Manager Global : find View Locked:421) {main}**

I tried to solve this issue. In my testing I didn't get any of the following error in my app. I got this issue from play store report. Can any help me to solve this problem?

Comment: could you please send the whole logcat ?

Comment: @Milad i just got only  Illegal Argument Exception (@Window Manager Global : find View Locked:421) {main} report

Comment: @Milad can you help me out to over this issue.

Comment: did you created a view and add them to root view in onCreate or onRestart?

Comment: @vandaics i did test with the app i can't found at which class the issue occurs in my testing i didn't find any issue.

Comment: @vandaics i got the error report from my play store